# Help with a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
select * from Properties 
join PPHL on PPHL.postcode = Properties.postcode
and PPHL.name = Properties.propertyname
and PPHL.id <> Properties.propertycode
where Properties.clientid = 1
```

I want to update all the Properties from the results of this query with the id from the PPHL table, does anyone know the correct sql I need to do this? I am running this on mysql 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set clause goes after the table joins. See the [MySQL documentation for UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for syntax help.

```
UPDATE Properties 
    JOIN PPHL ON PPHL.postcode = Properties.postcode
             and PPHL.name = Properties.propertyname
             and PPHL.id <> Properties.propertycode

SET Properties.propertycode = PPNL.id
WHERE Properties.clientid = 1
```